# No URI javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"SearchAndList"). Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb

I am having trouble to unmarshall my data. I got the following error:

> ERROR FsceClient - Error in getDataInMatches : unexpected element
>   (uri:"", local:"SearchAndList"). Expected elements are (none)
>   requested params:+COUNTRY=US+YR=2016+DIV=Ford+WB=122.0
>       javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"SearchAndList"). Expected elements are (none)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)

This is my xml file:

```
<SearchAndList>
    <fvd>
        +COUNTRY=US+YR=2016+DIV=Ford+WB=122.0
    </fvd>
    <sol>
    <rsi>
        <sType>Ss</sType>
        <mHave>true</mHave>
        <toAr>0</toAr>
        <toAr>0</toAr>
        <toAr>22</toAr>
    </rsi>
    <rsi>
        <sType>ssa</sType>
        <mHave>true</mHave>
        <toAr>77</toAr>
    </rsi>
    </sol>
    <sol>
        <rsi>
            <sType>sve</sType>
            <mHave>false</mHave>
            <toAr>0</toAr>
            <toAr>21</toAr>
        </rsi>
    </sol>
</SearchAndList>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your XML schema in addition to the XML.  It also would help if we could see the code that does the unmarshalling.

Comment: I am pretty new with web services stuff. I am using anotation: this is my code for: UnmarshallerPool searchAndListPool = null;
   JAXBContext jaxbContext_SearchAndList = JAXBContext.newInstance(SearchAndList.class);
   searchAndListPool = new UnmarshallerPool(MAX_POOL_SIZE, jaxbContext_SearchAndList);
   searchAndListPool.initialize();
   
   Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
   InputStream in = makeCachedGETServerCall(finalURL);
   unmarshaller = searchAndListPool.getResource();
   return (SearchAndList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);

Comment: @XmlRootElement(name="searchAndList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchAndList extends ArrayList<Sol> implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 2447564738604L;
 @XmlElement
 private String fvd;

 public SearchAndList() {
  super();
 }
 
 public void setFvd(String fvd) {
  this.fvd = fvd;
 }

 public String getFvd() {
  return fvd;
 }
 @XmlElement(name="sol", type=Sol.class)
 public List<Sol> getSol() {
  return this;
 }
}

Comment: Someone can help me please?

Comment: At the bottom of your question are shaded rectangles showing keywords (java, xml, rest, jaxb).  Under those is an “edit” link.  Please use that link to alter your question and place your code there.  As you can see, code is very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Could you please check and possibly accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is encountered when the XSD schema does not contain element definitions and only contains class definitions (i.e. complex types).

e.g. for this XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The object factory created is like this:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
   public ObjectFactory() {
   }
   public Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

BUT FOR THIS XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo" type="foo" nillable="true"/>
  <xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The ObjectFactory class created by JAXB is:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
    private final static QName _Foo_QNAME = new QName("", "foo");
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }
    public Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "foo")
    public JAXBElement<Foo> createFoo(Foo value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Foo>(_Foo_QNAME, Foo.class, null, value);
    }
}
```

You can see that the JAXBElement wrapper creation method is also added. With the second XSD, the unmarshaller knows what to do when it encounters a tag with name "foo". So if you have an XSD, add "element" definitions as well as the complex types.

----- EDIT---- 
The sample unmarshaller code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Object result = ((JAXBElement<Object>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(stream)).getValue();
```