# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (URI:"", local:"NewDataSet"). Expected elements are <{http://www.webserviceX.NET}string>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, xjc

I have searched a lot through this website and tried several things but I haven´t fixed this error yet. The error I am getting is:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (URI:"", local:"NewDataSet"). Expected elements are <{http://www.webserviceX.NET}string>
```

When trying to unmarshal I get the previous error. I am calling a webservice and I get the following result, which is a String with the following XML structure:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Book>1</Book>
    <BookTitle>Genesis</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>2</Book>
    <BookTitle>Exodus</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>3</Book>
    <BookTitle>Leviticus</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>4</Book>
    <BookTitle>Numbers</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>5</Book>
    <BookTitle>Deuteronomy</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>6</Book>
    <BookTitle>Joshua</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>7</Book>
    <BookTitle>Judges</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>8</Book>
    <BookTitle>Ruth</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>9</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Samuel</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>10</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Samuel</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>11</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Kings</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>12</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Kings</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>13</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Chronicles</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>14</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Chronicles</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>15</Book>
    <BookTitle>Ezra</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>16</Book>
    <BookTitle>Nehemiah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>17</Book>
    <BookTitle>Esther</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>18</Book>
    <BookTitle>Job</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>19</Book>
    <BookTitle>Psalms</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>20</Book>
    <BookTitle>Proverbs</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>21</Book>
    <BookTitle>Ecclesiastes</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>22</Book>
    <BookTitle>Song of Solomon</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>23</Book>
    <BookTitle>Isaiah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>24</Book>
    <BookTitle>Jeremiah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>25</Book>
    <BookTitle>Lamentations</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>26</Book>
    <BookTitle>Ezekiel</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>27</Book>
    <BookTitle>Daniel</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>28</Book>
    <BookTitle>Hosea</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>29</Book>
    <BookTitle>Joel</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>30</Book>
    <BookTitle>Amos</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>31</Book>
    <BookTitle>Obadiah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>32</Book>
    <BookTitle>Jonah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>33</Book>
    <BookTitle>Micah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>34</Book>
    <BookTitle>Nahum</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>35</Book>
    <BookTitle>Habakkuk</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>36</Book>
    <BookTitle>Zephaniah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>37</Book>
    <BookTitle>Haggai</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>38</Book>
    <BookTitle>Zechariah</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>39</Book>
    <BookTitle>Malachi</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>40</Book>
    <BookTitle>Matthew</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>41</Book>
    <BookTitle>Mark</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>42</Book>
    <BookTitle>Luke</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>43</Book>
    <BookTitle>John</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>44</Book>
    <BookTitle>Acts</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>45</Book>
    <BookTitle>Romans</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>46</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Corinthians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>47</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Corinthians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>48</Book>
    <BookTitle>Galatians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>49</Book>
    <BookTitle>Ephesians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>50</Book>
    <BookTitle>Philippians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>51</Book>
    <BookTitle>Colossians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>52</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Thessalonians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>53</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Thessalonians</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>54</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Timothy</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>55</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Timothy</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>56</Book>
    <BookTitle>Titus</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>57</Book>
    <BookTitle>Philemon</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>58</Book>
    <BookTitle>Hebrews</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>59</Book>
    <BookTitle>James</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>60</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 Peter</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>61</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 Peter</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>62</Book>
    <BookTitle>1 John</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>63</Book>
    <BookTitle>2 John</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>64</Book>
    <BookTitle>3 John</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>65</Book>
    <BookTitle>Jude</BookTitle>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Book>66</Book>
    <BookTitle>Revelation</BookTitle>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

The code I am using is the following one:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    BibleWebservice service = new BibleWebservice();
    BibleWebserviceSoap soap = service.getBibleWebserviceSoap();
    String bookTitles = soap.getBookTitles();
    try {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(bookTitles);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Book book = (Book)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
        //Book book = ((JAXBElement<Book>) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(sr)).getValue();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println(bookTitles);
}

}
```

My Book class is:

```
    //
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.01.25 at 03:45:20 PM GMT 
//


package filesgeneratedfromxml;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="NewDataSet">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
 *                   &lt;element name="Table">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;complexContent>
 *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                           &lt;sequence>
 *                             &lt;element name="Book" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}byte"/>
 *                             &lt;element name="BookTitle" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                           &lt;/sequence>
 *                         &lt;/restriction>
 *                       &lt;/complexContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                 &lt;/choice>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "newDataSet"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "string")
public class Book {

    @XmlElement(name = "NewDataSet", required = true)
    protected Book.NewDataSet newDataSet;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the newDataSet property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Book.NewDataSet }
     *     
     */
    public Book.NewDataSet getNewDataSet() {
        return newDataSet;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the newDataSet property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Book.NewDataSet }
     *     
     */
    public void setNewDataSet(Book.NewDataSet value) {
        this.newDataSet = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
     *         &lt;element name="Table">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;complexContent>
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                 &lt;sequence>
     *                   &lt;element name="Book" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}byte"/>
     *                   &lt;element name="BookTitle" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                 &lt;/sequence>
     *               &lt;/restriction>
     *             &lt;/complexContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *       &lt;/choice>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "table"
    })
    public static class NewDataSet {

        @XmlElement(name = "Table")
        protected List<Book.NewDataSet.Table> table;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the table property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the table property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getTable().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link Book.NewDataSet.Table }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<Book.NewDataSet.Table> getTable() {
            if (table == null) {
                table = new ArrayList<Book.NewDataSet.Table>();
            }
            return this.table;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;complexContent>
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *       &lt;sequence>
         *         &lt;element name="Book" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}byte"/>
         *         &lt;element name="BookTitle" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *       &lt;/sequence>
         *     &lt;/restriction>
         *   &lt;/complexContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "book",
            "bookTitle"
        })
        public static class Table {

            @XmlElement(name = "Book")
            protected byte book;
            @XmlElement(name = "BookTitle", required = true)
            protected java.lang.String bookTitle;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the book property.
             * 
             */
            public byte getBook() {
                return book;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the book property.
             * 
             */
            public void setBook(byte value) {
                this.book = value;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the bookTitle property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link java.lang.String }
             *     
             */
            public java.lang.String getBookTitle() {
                return bookTitle;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the bookTitle property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link java.lang.String }
             *     
             */
            public void setBookTitle(java.lang.String value) {
                this.bookTitle = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My package-info class is:

```
 //
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.01.25 at 03:45:20 PM GMT 
//

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package filesgeneratedfromxml;
```

And my ObjectFactory class is:

```
    //
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.01.25 at 03:45:20 PM GMT 
//


package filesgeneratedfromxml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the filesgeneratedfromxml package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: filesgeneratedfromxml
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Book.NewDataSet.Table }
     * 
     */
    public Book.NewDataSet.Table createStringNewDataSetTable() {
        return new Book.NewDataSet.Table();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Book }
     * 
     */
    public Book createString() {
        return new Book();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Book.NewDataSet }
     * 
     */
    public Book.NewDataSet createStringNewDataSet() {
        return new Book.NewDataSet();
    }

}
```

Any idea on why I am getting the error?

Comment: Why do you unmarshal in Book? I had expected that is NewDataSet. Your annotation XmlRootElement is string, but it should be NewDataset. I'm very confused about the hierarchy in your Book-class...

Comment: Hi. It is already fixed. Just had to add header "<string xmlns=\"webserviceX.NET\">" and footer "</string>" to the String returned by the webservice "bookTitles" . Thanks for your help!

Comment: @IQV when I call the webservice via webbrowser, the xml returned contains the <string> element with the namespace, but when calling it from the client, just return with no <string> element. No idea why.

Comment: Try this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155719/1644618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already fixed. Just had to add header

```
<string xmlns=\"webserviceX.NET\">
```

and footer

`</string>`

to the String returned by the webservice "bookTitles" . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `JAXBElement` when you are getting unexpected element:

```
public static Car unmarshal(File file) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBElement<Book> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
            file), Book.class);
    Book book= root.getValue();

    return book;
}
```

Comment: Hi. It is already fixed. Just had to add header  "<string xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">" and footer "</string>" to the String returned by the webservice "bookTitles" . Thanks for your help!